Any element/text should be in seprate <p> from the <p> tag using xslt
We want to create the separate <p> tag for any tag/text appearing in the <p> tag in sequence means content could not mismatch.
Thanks and Please help me
Input:
<kk><p id="p_aj3uga5iqfuzmmw"> Some text is here
        <table outputclass="ruled" id="ko4xjv6txx">
            <tgroup cols="2" id="67dc15u6ud">
                <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="40" id="jc204r3bna"/>
                <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="60" id="o79df53wog"/>
                <thead id="kih5dc7um1">
                    <row id="ve4ln370t8">
                        <entry id="yi4lwe9p51">head text is here</entry>
                        <entry id="dwl1ol06ju">head text is here</entry>
                    </row>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="62gug7qywr" class="- topic/tbody ">
                    <row id="7wdson97xv" class="- topic/row ">
                        <entry id="3at6ja8goj">text is here</entry>
                        <entry id="m33p8e0e9f">text is here</entry>
                    </row>
                </tbody>
            </tgroup>
        </table>
        <b id="nryvddsy5o"><i id="cs8atnkc9h">Component auditor responsibilities</i></b> some text here
    </p></kk>

Expected output:
<kk><p id="p_aj3uga5iqfuzmmw"> Some text is here</p>
<table outputclass="ruled" id="ko4xjv6txx">
    <tgroup cols="2" id="67dc15u6ud">
        <colspec colname="c1" colnum="1" colwidth="40" id="jc204r3bna"/>
        <colspec colname="c2" colnum="2" colwidth="60" id="o79df53wog"/>
        <thead id="kih5dc7um1">
            <row id="ve4ln370t8">
                <entry id="yi4lwe9p51">head text is here</entry>
                <entry id="dwl1ol06ju">head text is here</entry>
            </row>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="62gug7qywr" class="- topic/tbody ">
            <row id="7wdson97xv" class="- topic/row ">
                <entry id="3at6ja8goj">text is here</entry>
                <entry id="m33p8e0e9f">text is here</entry>
            </row>
        </tbody>
    </tgroup>
</table>
<p><b id="nryvddsy5o"><i id="cs8atnkc9h">Component auditor responsibilities</i></b> some text here</p></kk>

My XSL file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(., text())">
                <p><xsl:apply-templates select="text()[1] except table | text() | *"/></p>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="table[1]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="table[1]"/>        
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="*[1]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>        
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="table">
        <table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>


If you wrap any child node into the parent with e.g. <xsl:template match="p"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template><xsl:template match="p/node()"><xsl:element name="{name(..)}" namespace="[namespace-uri(..)}"><xsl:sequence select="."/></xsl:element></xsl:template> you should get some result. It is not clear, however, how you want to treat white space in text nodes.

Your first text-node get's into it's own p.
Your last text-node get 's into a p together with it's preceding-sibling b.
Are there any other text-nodes that needs special treatment?

Thanks @MartinHonnen, I will try with your suggestion and let you know

Thanks @SiebeJongebloed Whatever any element/node is coming inside  and  element is inside the  tag, should be every element/node will be in  tag

@MartinHonnen it's looking but little fine tune newline and space is also appearing in   tag. we do not want to newline and spaces in . Another issues if any tag/element in appearing in text also converting in  tag but this should not be happen

Why are (in the expected output:) the b and text in in one p combined? Both b and text nodes are children of p. Therefore this text-node should be in a separate p?

@SiebeJongebloed That's the scenario is appearing in the input but our main goal is if  is appearing in the  tag then our output will be as per expected output, if any content is appearing before the table should be in , if any content is appearing after the table should be in  tag

It is not clear what you consider a text node, the first child node of the p element is a text node starting  Some text is here followed by a line break followed by the spaces   so see before the opening <table ...> tag. My suggested code wraps the complete text node into a p element, I have not understood whether you have any clear requirement specification on how to deal with white space/line breaks in text nodes.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
  version="2.0">
  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p[table]">
    <!-- If p contains table  put everything before and after table in p and the table it self not in p-->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="if(self::table) then 1 else 0">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-group()[self::table]">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>


Thanks @SiebeJongebloed,It's working fine
